# twitterlibphp - can't follow at all

Tags: php, twitter

This is driving me absolutely crazy. I can update my status using twitterlibphp and I can get followers, following etc but no matter what I do $o->follow(twitter_id) just will not work. It responds with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <request>/notifications/follow.xml</request>
  <error>There was a problem following the specified user.</error>
</hash>
```

I've done some googleling, read through the library source and can't see what on earth I'm doing wrong. If you are in the london area I will probably buy you a pint if you know whats going on... The code is pretty simple:

```
$twitter = new Twitter($username, $password);
$xml = $twitter->getFriendIDs(array('user'=>$user));
$output = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($output->id as $id) {
   echo $twitter->follow($id);
}
```

*(The $user var just comes from a textbox on a form - all that works fine and the foreach loops over the ID's)*

But no dice. Anyone having the same issue or am I doing something silly? I've also tried running $twitter->verifyCredentials() beforehand but still the same unhelpful error. If i put in a random (non-existant) account then it tells me that that user was not found so I know its kinda working.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the following [tidbit](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/twitter/docs) after some more googling:

> *follow*
>
> Enables notifications for updates from
>   the specified user to the
>   authenticating user. This method
>   requires the authenticated user to
>   already be friends with the specified
>   user otherwise the error "there was a
>   problem following the specified user"
>   will be returned.

Hopefully calling $o->createFriendship($id) and then follow will work :) I'm amazed thats not in the examples or more prominent in the docs...

Comment: and FYI for any others that come across this - that worked :)